# Keep alive processing after close the google extension "popup"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I started create extension, I didn't know that "popup" always reinit after open.

Is it have some options for off this behavior?

"background" page is not good for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default behavior, just like closing-opening a tab/window.

Using background page (`persistent: true`) is a good way, it lives through the entire browser lifetime.

However, if for some reason you are not planning to use background page, I guess [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) or [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is also a good way, taking the former for example, you can store data through `chrome.storage.local.set` while retrieving the data via `chrome.storage.local.get` every time the popup page opens.

Comment: It's a pity.
Yeah, I thought about `chrome.storage` in a bad case.
I didn't know about `persistent: true`, it's nice.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `persistent: true` is the default, by the way.